# Where do I put my methods with MVC?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I have a folder `/controllers` with controllers and another `/models` where i put my models with get/sets.

Now, where is the usual place to put the methods to get data from the db,etc...?

**In my last project I put it under the get/sets and it was a bit confusing.**

Any helP?

Comment: I like to have an intermediate `services` layer which communicates with both models and controllers in my projects. Controller calls service -> service calls model -> model returns data to service -> service returns data to controller.

Comment: There is no one universal answer.  You're basically asking "How should I design my application?"  We can't know.  You would put your methods on the objects where it intuitively makes sense to put them.  And you would create objects which intuitively make sense for the business domain and application technologies you're using.

Comment: a very good tutorial to start https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-element-collection-demo/

Answer (score 0):

For database you can have a DTO folder, but you could also have a intermediate Service folder where you put all the business rules. I like having a separate DTO object to make mocking easier too.

Answer (score 0):

For strictly data access, spring boot handles most of CRUD. You just need to config spring to know you have a data access layer. @JpaRepository does this. This is probably where you should start looking. For custom data calls you're going to have to write custom methods inside the classes that make up the data access laters.

Your question is extremely broad but I hope I've given you enough to look at.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/